# Select user id with a minimum value SQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

How do I select from a database table a user id that is linked to the minimum value of the table

for example

```
User ID    Pending
-------    --------
0          5
1          4
2          7

'$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT MIN(write_pending) FROM writerdata_tb");
            if ($temp = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {

            }'
```

in this case, I would want the data that is returned to have the value of the user with the least pending, in this case being user 1. How do I set up a MySqli query to handle this? And what would be the best way to save the result as a variable for use in the rest of my php?

Comment: Where's the HTML and PHP codes?

Comment: '$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT MIN(write_pending) FROM writerdata_tb");
                if ($temp = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {
                    
                }'

that's what I have so far, I want to make a query and store the user id as a variable

Comment: This question is so common it has its own tag [greatest-n-per-group].

Comment: `select user id from table ORDER by pending DESC limit 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably something like this, but it depends heavily on what your table structure is like. I've assumed you've got a generic users table with some IDs and this pending value you've mentioned.

```
SELECT userID FROM users WHERE pending = ( SELECT MIN(pending) FROM users );
```

The nested Select statement gets the smallest pending value in that column of your table, then you can refine your select userID statement by forcing pending to be the value returned from that nested select call.

***UPDATE***

To clarify your followup question of processing results, here's a modification of the code you provided:

```
$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT userID FROM users WHERE pending = ( SELECT MIN(pending) FROM users )");

if($resultSet->num_rows > 0) {
    //We use a while loop here, in the event that there are multiple rows
    while($row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["userID"]; //Accessing the rows index at "userID"
    }
}
```

Comment: so the query looks for the minimum value in pending first and then uses that as a pointer to the userID. I'm implementing it now, thank you

Comment: Yes, the subquery returns the minimum of all pending values, and you can search for the userID that is associated with that value. Please accept the answer if this solved it for you. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I shall, but also, how do i catch the result and store it as a variable? I've been using a $resultset method but I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do it

Comment: $resultset is simply a variable name, not a method. To process the results of a table query you store them in a variable (like you have) then process every row inside that set of results. Your sample only has one row in the result, because you have unique values for pending (I don't know if this is always true) but look at the update to my answer above to see an example.

Comment: Yes that's what I was wondering. While I'm still here, do you know if you can use mysql real escape strings on cookies?

Comment: Please create a new question, or better yet Google it first. This comment thread is not the place for alternate discussions.